# Solving 2-degree equations in 4 variables.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

A system of equations of degree 2 with 4 variables：
$$
\frac {\sqrt{z^2+w^2}} {{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}}} = m
$$
$$
k \cdot {x} + c = y
$$
$$
(x - z)^2 + (y - w)^2 = d
$$
$$
\frac {x} {y} = \frac {z} {w}
$$
$
a,m,k,c,d
$
are constants,so calculating the values of $x,y,z,w$

I tried using the elimination method to solve this system of equations, but during the operation, there was a situation where one unknown number was the root result of another unknown number. I feel that the elimination method is unlikely to solve this problem, so I asked if there are any other solutions.

At present, I use iterative method to solve this equation, making small adjustments to m each iteration, and using the third equation to determine the error of the result. However, it is obvious that this method is inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: I tried using the elimination method to solve this system of equations, but during the operation, there was a situation where one unknown number was the root result of another unknown number. I feel that the elimination method is unlikely to solve this problem, so I asked if there are any other solutions.

Comment: At present, I use iterative method to solve this equation, making small adjustments to m each iteration, and using the third equation to determine the error of the result. However, it is obvious that this method is inefficient.

Comment: Maple 2024 and Mathematica 14 can solve for general parameters. For example for only unknown x
 Maple gives a several pages of solution !!!

Comment: Using the second equation, you can eliminate $y$ from the other equations, and end up with a system of $3$ equations of degree 2 in the three unknowns $x, z, w$.